# Error importing Cython module after successful catkin_make

Tags: python, c++, import, cython, catkin

I'm trying to expose C++ class and method to Python. Therefore I opted to use Cython to wrap the two. C++ code is a part of a catkin package, so I researched ways how to integrate Cython compilation inside `catkin_make`.

In my dummy example, there's a C++ class `A`, and a factory method `get_a()` which returns a `shared_ptr<A>`. On Cython side I created one pair of files `example_a.pxd` and `example_a.pyx` which wrap C++ class `A` into `PyA`, and `c_example_a_factory.pxd` and `example_a_factory.pyx` which wrap a C++ method `get_a()` into a Cython method of the same name. I both `import` and `cimport` class `PyA` from `example_a` module to `example_a_factory`, and it compiles nicely. However, when I try to import `example_a_factory` from python, I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named example_a
```

I found several repos that try to accomplish something similar to what I need, in regard to build process, and I followed those examples: [ros_cython_example](https://github.com/longjie/ros_cython_example), [cython_catkin_example](https://github.com/marcoesposito1988/cython_catkin_example), [cython_cmake_example](https://github.com/thewtex/cython-cmake-example)

You can find my example code in [this repo](https://github.com/ilinojkovic/catkin_cython_example), together with instructions on how to run it. For easier reference, I'm posting Cython files here as well:

**example_a.pxd**

```
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr


cdef extern from "catkin_cython_example/example_a.hpp" namespace "example_a":

    cdef cppclass A:
        int get() const

cdef class PyA:
    cdef shared_ptr[A] c_a  # Hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping

    @staticmethod
    cdef inline create(shared_ptr[A] c_a):
        cdef PyA py_a = PyA()
        py_a.c_a = c_a

        return py_a
```

**example_a.pyx**

```
from cython.operator cimport dereference as d


cdef class PyA:

    def get(self):
        cdef int v = d(self.c_a).get()
        return v
```

**c_example_a_factory.pxd**

```
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr

from example_a cimport A

cdef extern from "catkin_cython_example/example_a_factory.hpp" namespace "example_a_factory":

    shared_ptr[A] get_a(int val) except +
```

**example_a_factory.pyx**

```
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr

cimport c_example_a_factory
from example_a cimport A, PyA
from example_a import PyA


def get_a(val):
    cdef shared_ptr[A] c_a = c_example_a_factory.get_a(val)
    return PyA.create(c_a)
```

I tested putting everything inside one module, and the code works fine, but I'd rather have separate modules for easier maintainability and logic decoupling. All the help is appreciated!

Comment: and do you see a so-file (example_a.xxx.so) somewhere around? Was it compiled with the same python version?

Comment: In the first version of cmake files no, example_a.so wasn't generated. However, I just pushed some changes made in the meantime, which do generate the binary, and I still get the `ImportError`.